# How do I make black (dark) spots in a specific part of an object to prevent the player or viewer to see unnecessary spots?

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, normal-map

to describe my question in the title even more, let's say I have a corrugated metal texture, whether displaced or not, at the bottom of the texture, I want to add darkness so  the viewer nor the player can see what's below, just like having to remove a screw there will be a dark spot that will not let you see what's inside
Or if I have a gun barrel, I don't want the inside of my gun visible, I just want pitch black hole

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're going to have to describe to us what the 'bottom' is, geometrically, if you don't just want to fade an image to black in the appropriate dimension and use that as a UV texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick/Easy:

A trick I use a lot of the time is just to assign NO SHADER (no light response) to these areas.

[image]

Ideally, your scene composition and lighting should provide you with the effect you want with minimal changes.  In your gun barrel example, the gun is lit from the outside so you should have very little light inside the barrel.  There will be some, though, due to bounced lighting, so you can compensate for that by adjusting the exposure either in the compositor or in the *Color Management* pane in *Render Settings*.

[image]

In this very simple example I just brought the low tones down closer to 0.

Comment: thank you so much